# Fullcalendar Shows in double header name on daygreedWeek

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, vuejs2, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar for my app, the calendar shows doubled header of header bar (see attached image)

When I change time zone from local(in my case it is UTC+2) to for example UTC+12. It shows doubled header of the day/
Also if for example in UTC+2 current day is Friday(see image 3) in UTC+12 it must be Thursday(image 4) because of the time zones.
Calendar is not showing that .It  also "sets" extra atribute to element and

I am using:

- fullcalendar: v5.10.1
- Vue 2.14.6
- typescript

[image]

in inspector it adds extra div container what rises this kind of error if it manually is deleted it fixes the problem
[image]

[image: image 3]
image 4
[image: image 4]

Component how is added

```html
<FullCalendar
        ref="fullCalendar"
        :options="options || calendarOptions"
      />
<button @click="myMethod">Change time zone</button>
```

Vue plugins what added

```
import FullCalendarInteraction, { DateClickArg, ThirdPartyDraggable, DropArg, EventReceiveArg } from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import FullCalendarMoment from '@fullcalendar/moment-timezone'
import FullCalendarDayGrid from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import FullCalendarTimeGrid from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
```

Vue method what return params to calendar

```
 get calendarOptions () : CalendarOptions {
    return {
      plugins: [FullCalendarDayGrid, FullCalendarTimeGrid, FullCalendarInteraction, FullCalendarMoment],
      allDaySlot: false,
      //dateClick: this.handleDateClick,
      eventOverlap: false,
      events: [],
      eventTimeFormat: {
        hour: 'numeric',
        minute: '2-digit',
        meridiem: true
      },
      headerToolbar: {
          start: 'today prev next',
          center: 'title',
          end: 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
        },
      height: 'auto',
      hiddenDays: [0,6],//passed as var user can set what days to show
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      slotMinTime: "11:00:00",
      slotMaxTime: "19:00:00",
      slotDuration: { minutes: 15 },
      views: this.getViews(),
      validRange: () => ({
        start: "2022-02-17T07:25:14.552Z",//date for testing
        end: "2022-03-17T07:25:14.552Z"
      }),
      eventConstraint: {
        startTime:"11:00:00",
        endTime: "19:00:00"
      },
//... 
      timeZone: this.tmpstring,//on button press('Change time zone') changes timezone to 'Etc/GMT+12' from 'local' what is default value
//...
    }
  }
```

getViews() method

```
getViews () {
    let result = {}
    const _this = this

    switch(this.headerToolbar) {
      case 'arrows-only':
        result = {
          timeGrid: {
            titleFormat (verboseFormatting: VerboseFormattingArg) {
              return `${getMonthNumber(verboseFormatting.date.marker)}/${getDayOfMonth(verboseFormatting.date.marker)} ${getDayOfWeek(verboseFormatting.date.marker)}`
            }
          }
        }
        break
      default:
        result = {
          timeGrid: {
            dayHeaderContent (args: DayHeaderContentArg): CustomContentGenerator<DayHeaderContentArg> {
              return {
                html: `<div class="ci-calendar__day-name">${getDayName(args.dow)}</div><div class="ci-calendar__day">${getDayOfMonth(args.date,_this.timezone?.iana)}</div>`
              }
            }
          },
          timeGridWeek: {
            titleFormat: {
              year: 'numeric',
              month: 'long',
              day: 'numeric'
            }
          },
          dayGridMonth: {
            dayHeaderContent (args: DayHeaderContentArg): CustomContentGenerator<DayHeaderContentArg> {
              return {
                html: `<div class="ci-calendar__day-name">${getDayName(args.dow)}</div>`
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }

    return result
  }
```

Fullcode can be found here
https://pastebin.com/rmbEyT5S
Question is how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Added extra info

Comment: "Fullcode can be found here"...no. as per [ask] please provide a [mre] of the problem **here** in your question, otherwise  it can be closed as off-topic, as per this [help/on-topic] guidance. If you find there is too much code to post, then probably your example isn't minimal enough- only provide enough code to cause the problem...no more (and no less). Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson made changes to question.